# How to save JSON objects into an array

Tags: arrays, json, ruby, web

i want to save objects into an array. I have JSON objects and I want to save every object in an array to access every element alone.
Can anybody help me?

```
toArray = JSON.parse(res.body)

categ = Array.new
i = 0

toArray.each do |object|
newMyObject = MyObject.new(object)
categ = Array.new(i, newMyObject)
i = i+1
end
```

Comment: thank you for your comment. how can i do that? i have to access every single element in the json later.

Comment: As a note, Ruby strongly encourages using lower-case only variables and method names, so `to_array` is to be expected here. Capital letters are reserved for `ClassName` or `CONSTANT_NAME` situations.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
array_from_json = JSON.parse(res.body)
objects_array = array_from_json.map { |item| MyObject.new(item) }
```

The issue in your code is that you are creating a new array every iteration.

Comment: thank you. can you explain me, what the code does exactly?

Comment: Probably you don' know `map` method. That permit you to transform every element of an array and return a new array. In this case we are trasforming every element from the json to a MyObject object and the result is in the objects_array array object.

Comment: i get the error: "uninitialized constant MyObject (NameError)
Did you mean?  Object
 from test:51:in `each'
 from test:51:in `map'
 from test:51:in `<main>'
" Can you help me please?

Comment: Well, I don't know. I saw that in your code. I though you had a MyObject class defined.

Comment: How can i do that? Can you help me please?

Comment: I have a json objets with 100 elements and i want save every element in an object